# how to limit a line range in a region in a multi-line graphic

Tags: matplotlib

this is a multi-line graphic. the red line and blue line have a intersection， and in the right part of the intersection I want to remove the the red line. How should I do? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO.  If you want help, please provide your code and a picture (or link, and someone with higher rep will upload it) of the output and what you want changed.

Comment: Do you know the functions of the red and blue line, or the intersection point?